# Cannot find FromKeyedServices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-8.0

I'm using a new .Net 8, and I'm trying to inject some service with a new way of keyed services, but unfortunately i cannot find `FromKeyedServices`, is not found, it's belong to `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace, i added this but still i don't see it.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace SMSService.Persistence.ContextFactories
{
   public class ApplicationDbContextFactory<TDbContext>
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly DbContextOptionsBuilder<TDbContext> _optionsBuilder;

        public ApplicationDbContextFactory(
            IConfiguration configuration,  [FromKeyedServices("Sql")] IDbContextOptionBuilder dbContextOptionBuilder ,           ILogger<ApplicationDbContextFactory<TDbContext>> logger)
        {
```

Can anyone help me

Comment: Are you sure it is a .NET 8 app? Since .NET 8 has not yet been released, have you definitely downloaded the pre-release SDK? Is the project file set up correctly?

Comment: yep, downloaded the preview

Comment: What is the type of project this code is in? Console? Library? ASP.NET Core?

Comment: class library __

Comment: Does the class library have a reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions`?

Comment: nope, it didnot

Comment: So did you add it and see what happens?

Comment: Its worked, finally

Comment: Well there you go, fortunately Guru added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DI and [`FromKeyedServicesAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.fromkeyedservicesattribute?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) (since it's introduction in .NET 8 preview) in particular is part of the platform extensions which is not included by default in some of the project types (for example for `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK it will be included by default but for class library - will not).

For class library project install [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions) nuget.